TFiremonkeyContainer won't respond to Mouse Events
I am using the Firemonkey Container control (https://github.com/vintagedave/firemonkey-container) so I can make a VCL application but have some FMX elements.
I ran into a problem though where by I can't get the TFireMonkeyContainer control to respond to mouse events (e.g, MouseDown, MouseEnter, MouseMove, MouseUp etc).
Probably something to do with how messages are intercepted but I am not sure.
In the code I tried publishing:
OnMouseDown
OnMouseEnter
OnMouseMove
OnMouseUp
But as I say those methods never fire, oddly though OnDragOver and OnDragDrop work (already included in the component).
How do I get the TFireMonkeyContainer control to respond to Mouse events?
Basically I need to get the X and Y coordinate where the mouse is moving, and also when mouse down I need the X and Y coordinates too.
Thanks

Why would you even want for TFireMonkeyContainer to respond to any Mouse Events?   Wouldn't you rather have individual Fire Monkey controls that are within this container to respond to heir own mouse events?

Solved. Yes I have just realised this (sorry long time away from Delphi)

There is a flaw in your design.
You don't want your TFireMonkeyContainer to respond to any of the mouse events on itself. If it would then the FMX controls that are placed within the TFireMonkeyContainer would never register any of the mouse events since they would already be handled by TFireMonkeyContainer.
What you need to do is to setup proper events on each of the FMX controls.
